# C++ regex parsing numbers out of string

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I am trying to extract all the numbers from a string in the same row format. The following code extracts the numbers, but does not record the last row of 4s. How should I change my regex to get repeated row of numbers?

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

const string data  ="4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,"
"4,8,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,7,8,3,3,3,3,3,3,7,8,3,3,3,3,3,3,7,4,"
"4,6,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,6,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,6,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,4,"
"4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4";
int main() {
    regex e("[1-9]");
    sregex_token_iterator rit(data.begin(), data.end(), e);
    sregex_token_iterator rend;
    int i = 0;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> double_array;
    double_array.reserve(4);
    std::vector<int> row;
    row.reserve(40);
    while(rit != rend)
    {
        if( i ==  40)
        {
            double_array.push_back(row);
            row.clear();
            row.reserve(40);
            i = 0;
        }
        row.push_back(stoi(rit->str()));
        ++i;
        ++rit;
    }

    for(auto & disp_row : double_array)
    {
        for(auto & c : disp_row)
        {
            cout<< c << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's expected result exactly?

Comment: All I am really doing is just taking the string and storing each row as shown. so, there should be four vector<int> in the double array, and display just the same thing as in the string.  should be 40 ints in each row and 4 vector<int> stored.

Comment: Put the `if` statement after `++i;` and try again.

Comment: Imagine you have to put one number length rows to double_array - will your code work? It will not. You should exchange the order - first put element to inner row, do all incrementation, then test if row is full, add to double_array, and zero the inner index... BTW, you do not need `i` - you can just check `row.size() == 40`...

Comment: Sometimes you look at a problem, and think "I can solve this with a regex".  Now you have two problems: your original problem, and the regex.

Answer (score 0):

(I haven't actually counted your numbers; I am assuming they are as you say.)

When your loop finishes, you have processed all 40 numbers in the last block and they are sitting in `row`. If there were one more item in your list, then immediately before processing it the contents of `row` would get put into `double_array`. But there isn't, so they aren't.

You could fix this by doing the "do I have 40 items yet? if so, put them in `double_array`" test *after* each item is processed rather than before.